# Where have i gone wrong in solving this limit problem?

Tags: calculus, limits

**Problem**: Evaluate, if the limit exists: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2x)}}{x}$$

**My attempt**:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2x)}}{x}$

$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(2\sin^2 x)}}{x}$

$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{\sin^2 x}}{x}$

$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin\ x}{x}$

Since there is a standard formula for $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin\ x}{x}$, this limit exists and is equal to 1.

**My problem**: The answer given in my book is that the limit does not exist. There is a hint at the end of the problem which asks to use the concept of absolute value. I cannot understand why my method is not correct and by the way there is no absolute value in the expression.

Comment: $$\sqrt{u^2} = |u|$$

Comment: Those limits does not $\implies$ each other, to the extent your calculations are correct, they are equal.

Comment: @quasi, how is $\sqrt{u^2} = |u|$?

Comment: You are right @Henrik. Thanks for pointing out. Corrected.

Comment: @MrAP: Let u = -3. Then for that value of $u$
$$\sqrt{u^2} = \sqrt{9} = 3 = -u$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*: Note that $\sqrt{\sin^2 x} = |\sin x|$.

**Addendum**

By definition
$$|x|=\begin{cases}x,&x\ge0 \\ -x,& x<0.\end{cases}$$
With this definition it is straightforward to show that $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$ for any real number $x$:

*Suppose $n\ge0$. 
By definition $\sqrt n$ is the principal root of $n$. 
That is, $\sqrt n\ge0$ and $(\sqrt n)^2=n$. 
Thus, if $x\ge0$, then $\sqrt{x^2} = x = |x|$. 
If $x<0$, then $-x>0$ and so $\sqrt{x^2} = -x = |x|$.*

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{\sin^2 x} = |\sin x|$?

Comment: Because the square root of a positive number always is positive.

Comment: Because the sqrt symbol delivers only the principal square root (the nonnegative one), hence when $\sin(x)$ is negative
$$\sqrt{\sin^2 x} = -\sin x$$

Comment: @quasi, if $a=x^2$, isn't $\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{(\pm x)^2}=\pm x$?

Comment: @MrAP: No, $\sqrt{x}$ is a _function_ (i.e., single valued). Thus, for example, while it's true that the number $9$ has two square roots, $\pm 3$, the expression $\sqrt{9}$ yields $3$, not $\pm 3$.